# How to Run All Karate Feature files in a Single thread or is there any way to customize the thread count in Karate?

Tags: karate

I want to run each feature file, as well as each scenario in a feature file on a single thread.
Tried with **@parallel=false** tag, but this tag works at the feature level where it will run all the scenarios sequentially. but I need to run all the feature files sequentially

Comment: set threads to 1. FYI if the docs don't answer your question, assume what you need is not supported: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallelfalse

Comment: @PeterThomas Can you please update your documentation or something to ask your users to not "reference" you in the question body here?  This is apparently a recurring problem.

Comment: @Daedalus it is open-source, you are welcome to submit a pull request ;)

Comment: @PeterThomas Do we have any built-in keywords like threaCount=1 in karate to set the threadcounts?

Comment: @KundanBalse no we don't

Comment: @PeterThomas In that case, how can we Set the threads to 1?, I am using IntelliJ-Gradle. Please suggest

Comment: @KundanBalse kindly read the docs I provided in my first comment above, thanks.